# Separating SObject metadata into multiple folders inside a package (sometimes) causes errors during deployment

Tags: salesforcedx, project-structure

I'm am having some problems in a sfdx project where I am trying to gradually modularise the "happy-soup" metadata. I found out *what* is happening, but not the 100% of *why* or how to solve it.

Having multiple `classes` folders, even with more sub-folders in each (e.g. `selectors`, `services`, ...) is absolutely fine. However, when trying to do the same with `objects` I ran into problems when deploying the whole project. Specifically this error:
**"Must specify a non-empty label for the CustomObject"**

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to have the definition of the `object` and its "base" fields inside the `main` module. And then add more (feature) specific `fields` or `validationRules` into separate modules along with other metadata for the separate context.

I thought this was possible (as discussed in this related [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247472/is-it-possible-to-split-objects-in-a-salesforcedx-directory-structure)). And it seemed so for a while as the error does not happen always. The important difference in my context is that I *do not use packages* yet, rather just folders inside 1 package. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/248565/38924) to a similar question shows the same problem.

So it turns out that when there are multiple folders for the same object, it is important in which of them the object's `object-meta.xml` file is placed. If it is in the first one, then all is well. If it is not though, then the above error appears during deployment. And the reason seems to be that the main object metadata is then "lost".

I tried to compare the results of `sfdx force source convert --sourcepath force-app` in the various combinations:

1. All in `main/default`
2. 1 ValidationRule or Field in separate folder inside the same package

it turns out that the `package.xml` is always the same, but the `.object` xml file is missing the object level properties (e.g. `<label>Custom Object</label>`) when `.objet-meta.xml` was not in the *alphabetically* first folder. [repo with example](https://github.com/packocz/SObjectSeparation)

So what to do here? Is it wrong to have "feature specific" fields in modules other than the first one? (base schema)?

- There is no way to order folders by dependencies like you can do with (unlocked) packages
- I can't yet use packages as I have important metadata with unresolved dependencies going up/down the planned package structure
- it does not help to make the "module" or "package-to-be" folders be sub-folders of main (siblings of `default`). Same issue then

(the only thing I can think of is to prefix the folder names with "z_", but that seems daft)

Comment: This sounds more like a bug than a feature. Have you considered logging a bug with the cli team?

Comment: Done that now @sfdcfox. Just needed a little sanity check first I've not missed an obvious reason or piece of docs. Thanks

Comment: Link to CLI Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2230#issuecomment-1600733729